# How to change table background headers color on multiple pages by this code

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, makecell

**change the color of the background of the header to blue, not the header font color. thank you in advance**

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1-5]

%\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape} % see = sign
\small
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
‎\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X 
                    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                    >{\hsize=0.10\hsize}X
                    >{\hsize=0.15\hsize}X c
                              @{}}
\caption{Reported spectrophotometric methods for the analysis of Salbutamol sulphate}
\label{tab:mylongtable}         \\ \hline


  \thead[l]{Cmd}
& \thead[l]{Med} 
& \thead[c]{max}
& \thead[c]{Sol}
& \thead[c]{Sample}
& \thead[c]{Ref}   \\  \hline

\endfirsthead
%%%%
\caption{Reported spectrophotometric methods for the analysis of Salbutamol sulphate}
\label{tab:mylongtable2}         \\ \hline
  \thead[l]{Cmd}
& \thead[l]{Med} 
& \thead[c]{max}
& \thead[c]{Sol}
& \thead[c]{Sample}
& \thead[c]{Ref}   \\  \hline



\endhead
%%%%
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
%%%%
    \hline

\endlastfoot
%%%% table content see the = sign

 Salbutamol sulphate
& category
& \centering 500
& \centering deionized water
& \centering solid
&    [124]     \\ \hline

%%*********************************

Salb S.
& Spectroscopy
& \centering keto
& \centering methanol
& \centering solid
&  1    \\ \hline
%%*********************************


\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: does `\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\color{<desired color>}}` helps? welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: your question doesn't seem very clear. If you want  `\thead[l]{Cmd}` in red you can use `\thead[l]{\color{red}Cmd}` Also your tabularx column specifications seem incorrect the total width should add up to 5\hsize as you have5 X columns yours add up to 1\hsize

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Unrelated: your specifications for the `\hsize`s are incorrect. The total should be equal to the number of columns. If I understand well what you want, they should be `1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 0.50, 0.75`, not `0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.10, 0.15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood you correctly, than you looking for `\rowcolor` in the column hearers. with use ``thead{...}`this doesnt wotk well, so i sugest replace it with`multicolumn` encironment:

```
\newcommand\mcx[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
```

complete mwe is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\newcommand\mcx[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape} % see = sign
\small
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
‎\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize\centering}X
                    >{\hsize=0.10\hsize\centering}X
                    >{\hsize=0.15\hsize\centering}X
                            c
                              @{}
                              }
\caption{Reported spectrophotometric methods for the analysis of Salbutamol sulphate}
\label{tab:mylongtable}         \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!10}
  \mcx{l}{Cmd}
& \mcx{l}{Med}
& \mcx{c}{max}
& \mcx{c}{Sol}
& \mcx{c}{Sample}
& \mcx{c}{Ref}   \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
%%%%
\caption{Reported spectrophotometric methods for the analysis of Salbutamol sulphate (cont.)}
\label{tab:mylongtable2}         \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!10}
  \mcx{l}{Cmd}
& \mcx{l}{Med}
& \mcx{c}{max}
& \mcx{c}{Sol}
& \mcx{c}{Sample}
& \mcx{c}{Ref}   \\  \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\itshape\footnotesize continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
%%%%
    \hline
\endlastfoot
%%%% table content see the = sign
 Salbutamol sulphate
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    & category  & 500   & water & solid &    [124]     \\
    \hline
Salb S.
    & Spectroscopy  & keto  & methanol  & solid &  1    \\
%%*********************************
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]